# SQL query - remove duplicated

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.4, postgresql-9.5

I have a table with the following columns that matter:

```
ID | commentid
1 | abs345
2 | abs345
3 | abs345
4 | poly234
5 | poly234
6 | qq1r4c
7 | abs345
8 | abs345
```

And I intend to delete the lines where the commentid is duplicated, that is, when the ID numbering is not followed sequentially.
For this example, the lines with ID 7 and 8 would be eliminated.

Comment: What do you mean "the ID number is not followed sequentially"?

Comment: @GordonLinoff followed sequentially is for example: 1,2,3 with the same comment_id

Comment: Why would id=8 be removed? It follows id=7 sequentially. This starts looking like a Gaps&islands-problem...

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to return all rows except for the last comment id when it is duplicated?

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             count(*) over (partition by commentid) as commentid_cnt,
             max(id) over (partition by commentid) as max_commentid_id,
             max(id) over () as max_id
      from t
     ) t
where max_id = max_comment_id and commentid_cnt > 1;
```

EDIT:

Oh, I think I understand.  You want to keep only the first "grouping" of `commentid`.  Assuming that the is are sequential with no gaps, then one approach is:

- enumerate the rows for each `commentid`
- subtract the value from `id`
- If this is larger than the minimum id minus 1, then you are not in the "first" group.

This looks like:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             min(id) over (partition by commentid) as min_id,
             row_number() over (partition by commentid order by id) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where id - seqnum = min_id - 1
```

Comment: I want to return the rows when the commentid is duplicated. Duplicated happens when "ID" is not "+1"... for the same "commentid"

Comment: yes, it's that! Thanks :) if i input a given commentID it return the rows from the "first group". But if I want from the "second group" ? I already tried but I don't know how to do it...

Comment: @RenatoSantos . . . This answers the question you have asked here.  If you have a different question, then ask as a *new* question.